# call another function in button click just return empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to call a function to count the items in the cart. I put that function in AJAX when I click the add to cart button. The result of add to cart process is 'success' but `count_item()` doesn't return anything, or it only an empty page. What's wrong with my code?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  /* add product to cart */
  $(document).on('click', '.btn-addto-cart', function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var productname = $('#name' + id).val();
    var productprice = $('#price' + id).val();
    var quantity = $('#quantity' + id).val();

    if (quantity > 0) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "{{ url('shop/addtocart') }}",
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf_token"]').attr('content')
        },
        delay: 5000,
        data: {
          productid: id,
          name: productname,
          price: productprice,
          quantity: quantity,
        },
        success: function(data) {
          count_item();
          swal("Success", "Product success added to cart", "success");
        }
      });
    } else {
      swal("Warning", "Minimum add to cart must be 1", "error");
    }
  });

  /* to get total item in cart */
  function count_item() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "{{ url('shop/counttotalitem') }}",
      method: "GET",
      header: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf_token"]').attr('content')
      },
      delay: 5000,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: The `count_item()` function has no return statement (nor can it given its context, but that's a separate problem) - what behaviour are you expecting to see?

Comment: `count_item()` doesn't return anything, it just logs the AJAX response.

Comment: This won't solve your problem, but you can eliminate one ajax call by returning the number of items in the cart on the add to cart call.

Comment: @isnaini-barochatun are you familiar with promises or call backs? the result from making that web requests needs to be processsed. Like in this article, perhaps that's what you need to look into? http://michaelsoriano.com/working-with-jquerys-ajax-promises-and-deferred-objects/

Comment: @imvain2 hmm this is nice idea, actually i purposely separated the process of adding and counting total item in different controller functions to make the structure tidier